# Rails rvm: Howto prevent version confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

When setting up a new Rails project (version >= 3) I would like to prevent version confusion for future team mates by including the rvm "bundle install" in the current git project. Are there any recommended best practices for doing this?

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused about this. Are you trying to manage all the different versions of the gems your project relies on by committing all the gems to git?

Comment: @Brett Thanks for your feedback! To clarify: I would like my team mates to check out the project and not worry about gem versions. I want all the gem stuff within version control (Git or Hg or Svn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 is integrated with Bundler - versions of Gems you use are saved into `Gemfile.lock` file and they will be available for everyone else using your project.  `bundle install` will give your teammates the same versions of Gems that you have installed, so if I understand your question correctly you don't have to do anything above what Rails already gives you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! But: Do not assume that my team mates are using RVM. They will be checking out a current version from Git/Svn/Hg... I would like to ease their pain installing rvm (or rails) in the correct version.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept the answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Your teammates don't have to be using RVM, it's sufficient that they have Ruby and Rubygems installed, `bundle install` will work anyway.  Don't force others to use RVM, system wide Ruby and Gems installation is perfectly good too.

Comment: @maarons Thanks for your feedback, this sounds very promising. So, can I assume that "Rails/bundle" is similar to "Java/Maven"?

Comment: I don't know Maven well enough to be sure, but I think you can say that they are similar.  There is some info on Bundler page that might clarify it's purpose, there is a paragraph about sharing your application with others and usage of VCS http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to the rationale of bundler! This clarifies the situation for me. BTW: Maven is indeed very similiar (although it is also used for the actual build: Maven is considered the successor of Ant).